# How to set all raster pixels within a shapefile to null?

Tags: arcgis-pro, null, conditional, setnull

**I'm working with ArcGIS Pro 2.4.0.** I have a raster dataset consisting of several plots of crops. Within each plot, there is a small ground target that has differing reflective values than the surrounding crop. Since I am trying to extract the mean pixel value of the plots, I don't want the higher reflective values of the targets to skew the mean.

Here is a plot I am working with:

[image]

"A" denotes the main plot boundary, whereas "B" denotes the boundary around the reflective target.

**How can I set all the pixel values within B to null?** I've tried a SetNull equation, but typically the SetNull procedure involves setting all pixel values above/below a set value to null. If the solution lies within building a conditional statement, I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As 1st option, if you have vector data for big plot and reflective target, subtract reflective target from big plot ( it will give you a polygon with hole. Use [erase](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/erase.htm) tool for this operation). Then use [extract by mask](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/extract-by-mask.htm) tool.

As 2nd option, if you have attribute table for the raster, delete reflective pixel values from attribute table.